# How is ? used in regular expression in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this snippet

```
print(re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?', '','.exe1.exe.exe'))
```

The output is 1
If i remove ? from the above snippet and run it as

```
print(re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)', '','.exe1.exe.exe'))
```

Th output is again same. 
Although I am using ?, it is getting greedy and replacing all '.exe' with NULL.
Is there any workaround to replace only first occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

This is the signature for the `re.sub` function. Notice the `count` parameter. If you just want the first occurence to be replaced, use `count=1`.

`?` is a non-greedy modifier for repetition operators; when it stands next to anything else, it makes the previous element optional. Thus, Your top expression is replacing either `-script.pyw` or `.exe` *or nothing* with nothing. Since replacement of nothing by nothing doesn't change the string, the top and the bottom version (where empty string cannot be matched) will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark is making the preceding token in the regular expression optional
Use

```
print(re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)', '','.exe1.exe.exe', 1))
```

if you want to remove only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

`?` **is** greedy. So if it can match, It will.

For example: [`aaab?` will match `aaab` instead of `aaa`](https://regex101.com/r/fuEjEn/1/)

In order to make `?` non greedy, you must add an extra `?` (this is the same way you make `*` and `+` non greedy, by the way)

So [`aaab??` will just match `aaa`](https://regex101.com/r/fuEjEn/2/). Yet, at the same time, [`aaab??c` will match `aaabc`](https://regex101.com/r/fuEjEn/3/)